# Proof of Lucas' Theorem: Help in understanding contradiction

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I've tried understanding the below theorem by Lucas. The proof is by contradiction, but I don't see why there is a contradiction in $$(x^e)^{(k/q)} \equiv 1 (\mod n)$$ ?

Also is the theorem valid for $n=1$ ?

> ***Theorem $\mathit{10.4}\;\:$*** **(Lucas' Theorem)** $\,\,\,\,$ Let $n$ be a positive integer. If there is a positive integer $x$ such that $x^{n-1}\equiv 1\pmod n$ and $x^{(n-1)/q}\rlap{\,\,\not}\equiv 1\pmod n$ for all prime factors $q$ of $n-1$, then $n$ is prime. 
>   ***PROOF*** 
>  Let $\operatorname{ord}_nx=e$. Since $x^{n-1}\equiv1\pmod n$, by Theorem $10.1$, $e|n-1$. We would like to show that $e=n-1$, so assume that $e\neq n-1$. Since $e\,|\,n-1,\;n-1=ke$ for some integer $k\gt 1$. Let $q$ be a prime factor of $k$. Then: $$x^{(n-1)/q}=x^{ke/q}=(x^e)^{(k/q)}\\\equiv 1\pmod n.$$
>   which is a contradiction. So $e=n-1$; that is, $\operatorname{ord}_n x=n-1=\varphi(n)$, because $n-1=\operatorname{ord}_n x|\varphi(n)\leqslant n-1.$ Thus, $n$ is a prime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By initial hypothesis,  the author supposes that for any prime factor $q$ of  $n-1$, $x^{\frac{n-1}{q}} \neq 1  \bmod n$

In a part of the proof he assumes for later contradiction that $e \neq n-1  \bmod n$

But then he shows that for any prime factor $q$ of  $n-1$, $x^{\frac{n-1}{q}} = 1  \bmod n $ because $x^{\frac{n-1}{q}} =(x^e)^{(n/q)} =1  \bmod n$

This contradicts the assumption above.

Comment: What about the case $n=1$ ?

Comment: @user111854 $1$ is not a prime number, so this case fails.

Comment: There is no assumption about it being prime.

Comment: That's not what I mean. If the theorem were true for $n=1$, then $n=1$ would be prime. But $1$ is not prime, so the theorem does not hold for $n=1$.

Comment: @user111854 it's a very minor error from the author : it holds for every positive integer except $1$, so no big deal I guess.

Answer (score 1):

The contradiction is $x^{(n-1)/q}\not \equiv 1 \pmod n \Rightarrow x^{(n-1)/q}\equiv 1 \pmod n$, remember that by the definition of the order $\mathrm{ord}_n(x)$ we have $x^e \equiv 1 \pmod n$. It is true for $n=1$ because you cannot find an $x$ with $x^{n-1}\equiv 1 \pmod n$.